# Disable system swipe gestures and replace with libinput

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have Ubuntu 22.10 installed on old hp envy x360 and touchpad doesn't seem to work properly.

Two finger scroll up and down works fine. Two finger back and forth in browsers not recognized. Pinch in and out not working. All three finger gestures are inconsistent.

I managed to fix pinch in/out with libinput and xdotool and it's acceptable now

Now I need to disable three finger swipes to override them in libinput.

Interesting to add, that libinput debug handles all events correctly, also the laptop has touchscreen that also works flawlessly. Only touchpad doesn't.
I tried installing some Gnome extensions, but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you're running **Wayland**:

To activate gestures in Firefox:

1. Run this command:

   ```
   echo export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/use-xinput2.sh
   ```
2. Reboot.

To activate gestures in Chrome:

1. Open this page: chrome://flags/#ozone-platform-hint
2. Choose wayland